# How to get SNMP data using pysnmp?

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp

I want to get snmp data by using python pysnmp module. I was using command line to get SNMP data but now I want to read it using pysnmp module.

**SNMP command -**

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <ip address>:<port> xyz::pqr
```

I was using command like above. Now I tried something like below -

```
import netsnmp

def getmac():
    oid = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))
    res = netsnmp.snmpgetbulk(oid, Version = 1, DestHost='ip',
                           Community='pub')
    return res

print getmac()
```

I'm facing error - **import netsnmp. No module netsnmp**

Anyone can give me suggestion how I can get snmp data from the snmp server with python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using the `netsnmp` module as opposed to the `pysnmp`.

If you want to use `pysnmp`, then [this example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html#snmpv2c) may help:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                          CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                          UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
                          ContextData(),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))):
    if errorIndication or errorStatus:
        print(errorIndication or errorStatus)
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

UPDATE:

The above loop will fetch one OID-value per iteration. If you want to fetch data more efficiently, one option is to stuff more OIDs into the query (in form of many `ObjectType(...)` parameters).

Or you can switch onto the GETBULK PDU type which can be done by changing your `nextCmd` call into `bulkCmd` [like this](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/bulkcmd.html#pysnmp.hlapi.bulkCmd).

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        0, 25,  # fetch up to 25 OIDs one-shot
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))):
    if errorIndication or errorStatus:
        print(errorIndication or errorStatus)
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Keep in mind that GETBULK command support was first introduced in SNMP v2c, that is you can't use it over SNMP v1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your snippet but all data didn't get retrieved. Any Idea, why like that?

Comment: @IIya Etingof- How we can retrieve more than one say 10 OID data at a time?

Comment: @kit Updated my answer, let me know if this is what you need

Comment: @IIya Etingof- If I set more than one ObjectType with more than one OID's I'm not getting any data. How I can make use of GETBULK to do so. please give me sample snippet.

Comment: @kit added getbulk snippet

Comment: @IIya Etingof- Thanks. This is what I want.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof short question: it looks like you can indeed have multiple `ObjectType`s objects. Any idea if it's also possible to have multiple `UdpTransportTarget `s? Also, I'd appreciate any feedback on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238781/find-neighbours-of-a-switch-using-python-and-snmp-lldp)

Comment: You can't have multiple targets within a single SNMP command call (e.g, `bulkCmd`), but you indeed can have many command calls targeting its own target. These calls can be run sequentially (in a loop) or in parallel. For the latter you might want to do it asynchronously ([example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/bulkcmd.html)).