# How to monitor systemd service with snmp

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

Asked this already in server fault (https://serverfault.com/questions/934468/how-to-monitor-systemd-service-with-snmp) but got no answer so I'm trying it here since I want to retrieve the status with the `pysnmp` library in python.

So I have a Gunicorn service on my Ubuntu server.

First I added `proc gunicorn` to this file: `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.
But I'm not sure how to get the right values.

I've seen this question (How to monitor services with SNMP?) and tried this command `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2` to get the status of the service, but I got this message:

`HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)`

So I guess the OID is wrong or I have other configurations.

But I also found this answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496076/5549711).
So I think all I need is the OID of the service and then it should get me the value.

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                          CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                          UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
                          ContextData(),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))):
    if errorIndication or errorStatus:
        print(errorIndication or errorStatus)
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

How do I get the OID of my Gunicorn service?

Comment: It sounds like you first need to set up your snmpd in a way that it will keep an eye on the `gunicorn` process and report the outcome as a new OID (perhaps within some SNMP table). So I'd first focus on snmpd configuration for process monitoring.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof And how do I create a new SNMP table and configure it so it will watch the `gunicorn` process?

Answer (score 0):

did you extend your snmp.conf file. for example;

pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.1023.1.2.1 /bin/bash /etc/snmp/exampleScript.sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).